# How can I pipe the input audio of a Bluetooth headset into Google Now?

Tags: google-now, bluetooth-audio

How can I pipe the input audio of a Bluetooth headset into Google Now? I have Jelly Bean 4.1.1.

Comment: We can't speculate as to Google's plans, see the [FAQ].  I'm going to edit accordingly.